# Symfony, why use `@`?

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony version 3.* and I do not understand the

```
return $this->render('@AdminDash/Dashboard.html.twig');
```

My question is why use `@` with `AdminDash` ?

Answer (score 0):

In twig `@Something` is registered namespace as explained in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html)

Comment: @Something   is director ??

Comment: @Something is registered namespace in twig, works like an alias for directory path.

Comment: can you tall me render() finality ? and am not able to find Dashboard.html.twig file in directory  but it show page on browser

Comment: render - in symfony controller context will render twig template
@AdminDash - twig namespace - Depends on your bundles and so what path it will represent, you can find path with `bin/console debug:twig` console command, then under this path you will find your Dashboard.html.twig

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

Comment: set_time_limit(0);

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(['--env', '-e'], getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev', true);
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption('--no-debug', true) && $env !== 'prod';

Comment: if ($debug) {
    Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->run($input);

Comment: am use this code in /home/czqps0e0gil6/public_html/bin/console

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not wrong we use the =>'@SOME_BUNDLE/some_directory/some_file.html.twig' WHEN we are calling a file which isn't in AppBundle

and if we are in AppBundle we can use 
=>'AppBundle/some_directory/some_file.html.twig' 
OR 
'AppBundle:some_directory:some_file.html.twig' (maybe inside a controller or directly in twig template)